# Using try/catch for files in java

Tags: java, file, while-loop, try-catch, java.util.scanner

I'm having issues with using try-catch blocks in java. I'm writing a method that reads a user input file and prints it out to the console. This is what I have -

```
static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

public static String readingFiles(String fileout) {

    boolean find = false;

    while(!find) {
            try {
                File f = new File(input.nextLine());
                Scanner scan = new Scanner(f);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println("File Not Found.");

            }
    }
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();   


    while (input.hasNext()) 
    {
        list.add(input.nextLine());
    }

    String output = list.toString();
    return output;

}
```

It just seems like a mess and I have no idea what to do with it at this point. I had it working a few times, in that it would output what the file said but then if I purposefully entered the wrong file name it would loop "file not found" endlessly and I couldn't figure out how to return the loop to the beginning so the user could input a different file name.

Now it just does nothing even when i enter the correct file name, it returns nothing until i press enter again and it'll return file not found.
I call it using this in my main menu method -

```
      case 1:
            System.out.println("You chose Read File. Enter your file name: ");
            System.out.println(Question4.readingFiles(input.nextLine()));

            pressEnter();
            break;
```

edit: I now have this, which works but only prints the first line of my file?

```
public static String readingFiles(String fileout) {

    boolean find = false;
    String result = "";
    while (!find) {
        try {
            File read = new File(fileout);
            Scanner check = new Scanner(read);
            result = check.nextLine();
            find = true;
            check.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File Not Found. Please try again.");
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: You're not using `fileout` anywhere.

Comment: @shmosel i know i've tried using it in places but i'm not sure where to put it, i know a lot of the code is probably wrong i've been through like 50 different versions at this point. i just need some help understanding where im going wrong or what i need to do

Comment: You're not setting find to true anywhere, so it's always going to loop.

Comment: You're going wrong by trying random code variations in the hopes that something will work. You already know what you want to do; your task is to break down the process into logical steps and convert that into code.

Comment: @shmosel i went kind of crazy with the code trying to figure it all out haha. I've slimmed it down a bit now and trying to work out the next problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the following code.

```
public static void readFiles() throws Exception {
    int i = 1;
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    Scanner input = null;
    boolean fileFound = true;
    while(i <= 5){
        System.out.print("Enter a file name::::");
        input = new Scanner(System.in);
        if(input.hasNextLine()){
            try {
                File f = new File(input.nextLine());
                reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
                String str = null;
                while((str = reader.readLine()) != null){
                    System.out.println(str);
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println("File Not Found");
                fileFound = false;
                i++;
                continue;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("IOException");
                i++;
                continue;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Some Other Exception");
                i++;
                continue;
            } finally{
                if(fileFound)
                    reader.close();
            }
        }

        i++;
    }

}
```

Please note this method will read files 5 times. If you want to change it, you can pass an **int** parameter to the method and accordingly change the **first while** condition. Ensure you give complete path of the file with escape characters. For example, if file location is *'C:\abc.txt'*, you need to input *'C:\\abc.txt'*. Else, it will display '**File Not Found**' in console.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class readingFiles {

public static String readingFiles(String fileout) {

    try {
        //find a file with the same name as the value of "fileout"
        File f = new File(fileout);
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(f);

        //create a list to hold the file output
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();  

        //loop through the output line by line and add to the list
        while (scan.hasNext())
        {
            list.add(scan.nextLine());
        }

        //convert the list into a String value to pass back to the caller
        String output = list.toString();
        scan.close();
        return output;

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        //if file is not found, return a value of -1
        System.out.println("File Not Found.");
        return("-1");
    }


}
```

Okay a few things:

1. Your first while loop is unnecessary. I think you are trying to loop through files in the folder to look for a specific file name. However the `Scanner scan = new Scanner(f);` line already does this.
2. The reason your code infinitely prints "File not found." is because you never set the find condition to true to exit the loop.
3. You never use the `fileout` value you pass into the method. And your code asks the user for the filename input twice (once in the main method, once in the readingFiles method).
4. Using a list, then converting to String results in an output of `[line1, line2, line3, etc]` not sure if this is what you want.

As for why your second attempt prints only the first line, You have removed the while loop which loops through the file reading every line, therefore it only reads one line before stopping.

Comment: Java File has its own API to read /  write the file contents. It should not be through List as done here.